# How to make working path in HTML?

Tags: html

So, currently I'm making a website. It's an assignment. And when I tried to open it on different computer, it didn't work.

So, for example: "a href="file:///E:/assignment/main page/index.html#"

It did work on my computer, but it won't work on another. I need it to work at any computer.

Comment: `E:` refers to a drive on *your* computer.  That's why when you try this on *another* computer, this won't work.  To access it from *any* computer, you'll need to upload your web page to a server (or turn your computer into a server, but the first suggestion is probably easier and safer).

Comment: if you put your whole site (all html/css/js files) into a single folder, this will become your root. Then use relative paths

Comment: Another option is to save it to a thumb drive (or something), and open it from there.

Comment: Is `file:///E:/` your document root?

Answer (score 1):

There are two halves to your question:

**How do I make my website accessible anywhere?**

You need a *web server*, or you need to use a *hosting company*. GoDaddy, 1and1, HostGator, and other hosting companies have computers (web servers) that are configured to show their webpages to anyone in the world. They cost around $10 per month, and you end up with the ability to create links such as `http://example.com/myproject/index.html`

It's possible that your professor will let you put your web pages on one of his drives that are accessible anywhere on campus. Otherwise, a flash drive can do in a pinch. Put the files onto a flash drive and then bring the flash drive to class.

**Is there a better way to write links?**

Most websites use *relative URLs* in their links. For example, Stack Overflow, instead of writing every link as `http://stackoverflow.com/whatever`, will usually use a relative URL instead: `/whatever`.

There are a few simple rules that your browser follows when turning an `href` tag into a web address (in this example, we're starting from this page: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078748/how-to-make-working-path-in-html#15078792`)

- If the link starts with `http://` (or anything else that comes before
  a `://`), then your browser will take you exactly there. For example:
  `http://stackoverflow.com` takes you to the Stack Overflow home page.
- If the link starts with `/`, then the browser will take you out of
  any subfolders before executing the rest of the link. For example:
  `/election` will take you here: `http://stackoverflow.com/election`
- If the link starts with `../`, then it will send you exactly one folder
  up. This can be done multiple times. For example. `../` will send you
  here: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/` .
- If the link starts with a
  question mark, ampersand, or hash tag, (`?`, `&`, `#`) then it will usually append
  this to whatever page you are currently on. `#example` would take you
  to
  `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078748/how-to-make-working-path-in-html#example`
  .
- Finally, the browser will keep you in your current folder, then
  send you to that link, for example: `example` will send you here:
  `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078748/example`

Answer (score 0):

You must use relative paths not absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, you have to write:

```
<a href="./index.html">...</a>
```

to link to index.html a page which is in the same directory as your file index.html;

examples:
./my_page.html
use the "./" for linking pages in the same directory;

if the source and dest pages are in different folders, you shall use:
../my_page.html
or
./folder_path/my_page.html
according to the relative paths of the pages.