# CSS/Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, css

If fixed all of the issues I had yesterday, but when I drag my file into any brower, it just says "Hello" and doesn't include the element at all nor does it hide when clicked.

MyIndex.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <title>Mary Bishop</title>
    <link href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscript.js"></script>
            <div ID="contact">Hello</div>
        </body>
</HTML>
```

stylesheet.css

```
#contact {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #517F8F;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

jscript.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contact').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

I moved the body tag up to include all of the links (as you can see in the current HTML file), but that didn't change anything :( I'm so confused.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Start off by fixing your HTML. Put your title, link, and scripts in the head.

Comment: Even as it is, it works fine here (FF16, Chrome28 and IE10 in a Win7 box). What browser are you using? Do you have any errors in the console? Do you have javascript disabled?

Comment: Then stop dragging your file into the browser, and setup a proper web server (look into XAMPP).

Comment: You mentioned yesterday that you are using Google Chrome. Hit `[control][shift][j]`: this will open the Developer's console. If your page has a problem, it will usually record it under the `Console` tab ( It should look something like this https://uproot.us/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/chrome-console.png ). Do you see any errors there?

Comment: Yes!  It says it failed to load my stylsheet and my javascript sheet.  WOW, that's a really useful shortcut.  I'm not sure how to fix that issue, but at least I know what it is now.  Thanks, Chris!  You're a rockstar!

Comment: @j08691, i apologize, I do have my title, links, and scripts in the head section.  I think I copied it over incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have your files inside of other folders. For example, does the folder that contains your files look something like this?:

```
MyWebsite
    scripts   <-- this is a folder
        jscript.js  <-- this file is in the "scripts" folder
    stylesheets
        stylesheet.css
    MyIndex.html
```

If so, then you'll need to update your `<link>` and `<script>` tags so that they look like this:

```
<link href="stylesheets/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^ <- this should be the name of the folder 
                              that your stylesheet lives in
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jscript.js"></script>
                                    ^^^^^^^^
```

Basically, you need to add the appropriate folders to your links: otherwise they point to the wrong place.

You can quickly load the source code for your webpage by hitting `[control][u]` in Chrome. You will then see the JavaScript and Stylesheet URLs as links. You can click on these to follow them to see if they are working correctly.

[image: You can click on these links]

Comment: I'm using sublime text 2, so the folders that contain my files are through c/users/mary/mydocuments/ and on and on.  How do I make them smaller as part of just my website?

Comment: It's hard to know for sure without seeing what your folders look like, but this answer can give you more details about writing links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078748/how-to-make-working-path-in-html/15079041#15079041  In short, you need to understand where each of the three files is relative to each other. Are they in the same folder? Or are they in different folders? Can you open any of the JavaScript or CSS files in your browser directly? Like this:?  http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=e97b23688ee8

Comment: This is awesome help, Chris, thank you so much.  The links don't work, so I'm going to figure out how to save my files somewhere other than on my computer and getting the links to match where I have the files stored. Hopefully that fixes the problem and I can finish this project up.  Thank you for your time and attention.  Your assistance is invaluable to me.

Answer (score 0):

The <body> element should include only the <div> element. Otherwise, the code you posted seems to be working. Check to make sure this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Azn4u/) is what you want.

Html:

```
<div ID="contact">Hello</div>
```

CSS:

```
#contact {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #517F8F;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contact').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```